# JUNCTION OBJECT OWD if it masters has different OWD

Tags: security

User has Create,Edit access b ParentA, Read access on ParentB.
OWD on parent1 is Public write/Read
Owd on ParentB is Public Wirte/Read
Now I got the sharing access on Junction object is Edit Acces.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please [edit] this post to ask a clear question so that the community can help you.

Answer (score -1):

The first master-detail relationship you create on your junction object becomes the primary relationship. This affects the following for the junction object records:

Look and feel: The junction object's detail and edit pages use the color and any associated icon of the primary master object.

Record ownership: The junction object records inherit the value of the Owner field from their associated primary master record. Because objects on the detail side of a relationship do not have a visible Owner field, this is only relevant if you later delete both master-detail relationships on your junction object.

The second master-detail relationship you create on your junction object becomes the secondary relationship. If you delete the primary master-detail relationship or convert it to a lookup relationship, the secondary master object becomes primary.